# Start a file from batch file wait specific time then close

Tags: file, process, batch-file

I am trying to start a program through a batch file wait for some time and then close it. The code i wrote is this

```
@echo off
xfoil.exe < airfoil.txt > xfoil.out
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 10000
taskkill /IM xfoil.exe /F
```

unfortunately it doesn't work..! I am using Windows 7

Can you please help me out..?

Thank you

Comment: `unfortunately it doesn't work..!`, why?

Comment: because Xfoil is not closed after 10 seconds..!

Answer (score 0):

Your ping line has a couple of problems.  Firstly, the first ping result is always instant, so you should add 1 to the -n switch.  Next, 127.0.0.1 is a valid address, so the wait timeout is useless.

Try this instead.

```
ping -n 11 0.0.0.0 >NUL
```

That should give you a 10-second pause.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this doesn't work either. The program i want to close is run by commadprompt but i try to close the command prompt and doesn't close either this is what i wrote      @echo off
xfoil.exe < airfoil.txt > xfoil.out
ping -n 11 localhost >NUL
taskkill /IM cmd.exe /F

Comment: @user2019482 - Multiline code is hard to read in a single-line comment.  How about you edit your question instead?  And describe the symptom, please.  What isn't working?  The pause or the task killing?